# Identifying List Difference between Consecutive Rows for Entire Panda DataFrame Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of multiple columns and thousands of rows where one of the columns (called Customers) contains list of customer Ids:

```
|      Customers      |    
|---------------------|
|[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]|
|[A, C, D, E, F, G]   |
|[A, C, E, G]         |
|[G]                  |
```

I am interested to find the element differences between each row and its previous row for the Customers column, so my expected outcome should be:

```
|Customer Difference  |    
|---------------------|
|[]                   |
|[B]                  |
|[D, F]               |
|[A, C, E]            |
```

The Customer column is sorted meaning every row will contain all elements of its below row

I know I can use sets to find two list difference but not sure what would be a pythonic way to do this on the entire column.

Thanks

Comment: are those real lists? Can you provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a Series of **lists**, you could use a list comprehension with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) operations:

```
df['diff'] = [sorted(set(b).difference(a))  # the sorting step is optional
              for a,b in zip(df['Customers'],
                             df['Customers'].shift(fill_value=[[]]))
             ]
```

output:

```
               Customers       diff
0  [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]         []
1     [A, C, D, E, F, G]        [B]
2           [A, C, E, G]     [D, F]
3                    [G]  [A, C, E]
```

##### alternative

You could also convert to `set` and use `diff` directly:

```
df['diff'] = df['Customers'].apply(set).diff(-1).shift(fill_value={})
```

*NB. this approach is fancy but quite slower than the list comprehension*

output:

```
               Customers       diff
0  [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]         {}
1     [A, C, D, E, F, G]        {B}
2           [A, C, E, G]     {F, D}
3                    [G]  {E, A, C}
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customers': [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
                                 ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
                                 ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G'],
                                 ['G']]
                  })
```

Comment: Usign zip is clever, much better than creating another intermediate column like I was considering.